# Java OpenGL after displaying window, not responding appears

Tags: java, opengl

So any window I try to create (even empty ones), show up fine when I run it, but once I try to interact with it, move the window, close it, stuff like that, I get a not responding message. I even tried just copying code from a "how to make an OPENGL display tutorial" and even that went to not responding.

I have updated my all my drivers. Still not working.

```
package renderEngine;

import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.ContextAttribs;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.PixelFormat;

public class DisplayManager {

    private static final int WIDTH = 1280;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 720;
    private static final int FPS_CAP = 120;

    public static void createDisplay( ) {

        ContextAttribs attribs = new ContextAttribs(3,2).withForwardCompatible(true).withProfileCore(true);

        try {
            Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
            Display.create(new PixelFormat(), attribs);
        } catch (LWJGLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        GL11.glViewport(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    }

    public static void updateDisplay( ) {

        Display.sync(FPS_CAP);
    }

    public static void closeDisplay( ) {

        Display.destroy();
    }
}
```

AND

```
package engineTester;

import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;

import renderEngine.DisplayManager;

public class MainGameLoop {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DisplayManager.createDisplay();

        while(!Display.isCloseRequested()) {
            DisplayManager.updateDisplay();
        }

        DisplayManager.closeDisplay();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. I forgot to type Display.update();